# How to properly evaluate a string variable as data in jQuery.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass an array as POST data to php, but .post() doesn't seem to like my data string variable.

javascript:

```
var appData = {};
appData['name'] = 'Bob';

var post = JSON.stringify(appData);

$.post('/php/app.php', post, function (result) {
    console.log(post);
    console.log(result);
});
```

app.php:

```
if($_POST['name']) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Console returns:

```
{"name":"Bob"}
fail
```

Alternatively, if I spell out the string returned by stringify, things act as desired:

modified javascript:

```
$.post('/php/app.php', {"name":"Bob"}, function (result) {
    console.log(post);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Console returns:

```
{"name":"Bob"}
Bob
```

What's going on here?

Comment: In your first attempt you are sending a string, the result of `JSON.stringify` in the other an object which is the correct way.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to send JSON request payload. But `$.post` does not change the content type of the request to `application/json`, and PHP does not parse JSON payloads into the globals ($_POST,$_REQUEST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, if I spell out the string returned by stringify

This is not a string you are using, but an object, which `$.post` accepts.

The default encoding used by jQuery is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`, which means the actual string sent to the server is `name=Bob`, not `{"name":"Bob"}`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line:

```
var post = JSON.stringify(appData);
```

You actually want to pass the object as `data:` on the post in jQuery. Just delete that line and switch your passed var to appData

```
var appData = {};
appData['name'] = 'Bob';

$.post('/php/app.php', appData, function (result) {
  console.log(post);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `{name:"Bob"}`. Not using `"` on variable name.

(Sorry for the short post. I have not enoght point to comment).

**EDIT**

Don't use `var post = JSON.stringify(appData);` use `JSON.stringify(post, appData);`

Comment: `{name:"Bob"}` is equivalent to `var appData = {}; appData['name'] = 'Bob';`

Comment: {name: "Bob"} and {"name": "Bob"} both work. JSON.stringify() returns the latter.

Comment: Ohh, i didn't note te first JS, let check again.

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: `post` is undefined, and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the first argument is the value to stringify, the second and third optional arguments are for a replacer function and a String/Number for dealing with spaces.